# gRPC server timeout my request before my deadline time is hit

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-c#

When sending a message, my gPRC client set the deadline to 5 seconds from now. That said, the log indicate that my request was timeout within 3 seconds. Why is the server not honoring my timeout time?

```cs
DeviceRsp responce = client.SendDeviceCmd(deviceCmd, deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my DeviceCmd message have a timeout field that I needed to set. Basically, the deadline parameter is to set the timeout time on the client side, and the message timeout field is to set the timeout time on the server side.

```
deviceCmd.Timeout = 5000; // milliseconds
DeviceRsp responce = client.SendDeviceCmd(deviceCmd, deadline: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(10));
```